# Вывод 2-х таблиц одним запросом без дубликатов строк

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, select, объединение

У меня есть 2 одинаковых таблицы, но с разными значениями. Мне надо вывести все данные с этих таблиц одним запросом, но при условии, если ID будет повторяться, то эта строка будет проигнорирована.
Пример.

```
Таблица 1:
400, 21, 20
401, 28, 20

Таблица 2:
401, 29, 25
405, 40, 20
```

Надо чтобы строка 401 в таблице 2 не выделялась второй раз, если она существует в таблице 1.

Answer (score 0):

Например, так

```
SELECT * FROM table1
UNION
SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM table1);
```